# PyQt wheelEvent redirection and maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: events, recursion, pyqt, mouseevent, pyqt5

I have a QListWidget in a QDialog, and I want all wheel events to be redirected to the list, so I did this:

```
class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
    ...
        self.myList = QListWidget()
    ...
    def wheelEvent(self, scrollEvent):
        if not scrollEvent.isAccepted():
            scrollEvent.accept()
            self.myList.wheelEvent(scrollEvent)
```

It works fine until the scroll action tries to move the list beyond its limits. It seems that in those cases the QListWidget doesn't accept (ignores) the scroll event and transmits it (ignored) to its parent, the Form, which sends it again to the QListWidget, again and again until the "maximum recursion depth exceeded" error message is raised.

If the event is accepted before being redirected to the QListWidget, why when it comes back to the Qdialog is redirected again to the QListWidget? It seems that the "accept" flag of the event is not preserved (or QListWidget sets it back to "not accepted") and when it comes back to the QDialog is treated as a new event. How can I preserve those flags or make QListWidget to accept the event even if the list is at the top/bottom?

I have tried to define a subclass of QListWidget and accept the event at that subclass prior to redirecting it to the superclass, but same result, the event comes back to the Dialog as not accepted.

**EDIT**: Hi again! I've found a solution:

```
class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
    ...
        self.processingWheel = False
        self.myList = QListWidget()
    ...
    def wheelEvent(self, scrollEvent):
        if not self.processingWheel:
            self.processingWheel = True
            self.myList.wheelEvent(scrollEvent)
            self.processingWheel = False
```

Now when the QListWidget doesn't process the event (cause the list is at the top/bottom) the event reaches the QDialog again but this second time is not redirected to the QListWidget again. I suppose it's being redirected to the QDialog parent and there it's processed (doing nothing).

**If it's permitted I'd like to leave the question open because I'm still wondering why I had to manage the flag myself and couldn't use the isAccepted() flag associated to the event as in my first attempt. I'm afraid I haven't understood what's happening behind the scene with event flags during event propagation in Qt.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NB: this applies to Qt5 - things may work differently in Qt4.

When you call `self.myList.wheelEvent(scrollEvent)`, internally this will then call `QListView.wheelEvent(event)`, which will create a new `QWheelEvent`, and forward it to the appropriate scrollbar widget. If the scrollbar can't handle the event, it will set the accepted flag to false. This will result in the event being *immediately* re-propagated to the dialog, and the whole thing will go around again.

Once you send the event to the list-widget, you cannot re-set the accept flag until `myList.wheelEvent()` returns. But of course, if the list-widget's scrollbar ignores the event, it can *never* return, since it immediately enters an infinite regress.

Calling `event.flag()` before forwarding the event will have no effect, because the scrollbar re-sets it to false by default and will only set it to true if it explicitly handles the event.

Given all this, your solution using an external flag seems to be the only feasible one (it's somewhat analogous to the [blockSignals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals) mechanism).

Comment: Are you sure calling a "slot" manually, in this case calling QListView.wheelEvent(event), generates a new QWheelEvent?

Comment: I mean, I'm sending the event as a parameter, it doesn't seem logical to me that it creates a new one.

Comment: Sorry, just discovered newline is not accepted in the comments section. ;)  However the fact that scrollbar re-sets the event flag to false by default explains the situation, even if it's the same event all the time and no new one is created. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Pablovx. Yes, a new event is generated and passed to the scrollbar. See the qt5 source code for [QListView::wheelEvent](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/itemviews/qlistview.cpp#n815).